# ASP.Net Login control fails to authenticate after first login

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I have a problem with my website.
Until recently, my website login worked perfectly.
Then someday, I had to make a couple of changes to the default.aspx (the login site) and the web.config.

Suddenly login was only successful on every second try.
I tried to fix it but then it wouldn't log in at all.
After a rollback of the web.config and a new creation of default.aspx,
it still didn't work.

My next step was to check the Authenticate event.
The login was always reported as failed, no matter what I do, except the first time after I restart the web server.
So I started to check if the login was false. If so, I call Membership.ValidateUser to check if the user is really a fail.
Since the user is almost never authenticated, Membership.ValidateUser almost always jumps in, but only validates the user every second time.

Seeing this, I put some debug information into the LoginError Event.
I checked 5 times in a row (just to be sure that it is no sporadic error) if the user is valid.
Every single time works out fine.

So, Membership.ValidateUser doesn't work in the authentiocate event, but in the LoginError event.
I even tried to call Membership.ValidateUser twice in the authenticate event, but it still doesn't work.

I'm a bit lost for answers right now.
The SessionID Cookie is set, the authorized cookies are set, when the login is successful.

This is my login control:

```
            <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="#B5C7DE" 
        BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
        DestinationPageUrl="~/checkLogin.aspx" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1.2em" 
        ForeColor="#333333" MembershipProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" 
                                    style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-size:2em;font-weight:bold;">
                                    Anmelden</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" valign="middle" style="height: 50px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Benutzername:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Font-Size="1.6em"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="Der Benutzername ist erforderlich." 
                                        ToolTip="Der Benutzername ist erforderlich." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Kennwort:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" Font-Size="1.6em" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Das Kennwort ist erforderlich." 
                                        ToolTip="Das Kennwort ist erforderlich." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Anmeldedaten speichern." />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
                                        BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CommandName="Login" 
                                        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1.6em" ForeColor="#284E98" Text="Anmelden" 
                                        ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" />
        <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" 
            ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Login>
```

And this are my control events:

```
        Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles Login1.Authenticate
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()

    log.Debug("Login: 1." & e.Authenticated.ToString)

    If e.Authenticated = False Then
        If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
            log.Debug("Login: 2. Is Valid")
            e.Authenticated = True
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, True)
        Else
            If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
                log.Debug("Login: 3. Is Valid")
                e.Authenticated = True
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, True)
            Else
                log.Debug("Login: 4. Aint Valid")
                e.Authenticated = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

    log.Debug("Login: 5. End")
End Sub

Protected Sub Login1_LoginError(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login1.LoginError
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()

    log.Debug("Loginerror: 1. Entry")

    Dim a As Integer = 1

    Dim user1 As New BenutzerVerwaltung.clsUser("admin")
    log.Debug("Loginerror: 2. User1 admin: " & user1.UserName)

    Dim user2 As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser("admin")
    log.Debug("Loginerror: 3. User2 admin: " & user2.UserName)

    If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 4. Is Valid, Username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    Else
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 5. Aint Valid, username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    End If


    If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 6. Is Valid, Username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    Else
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 7. Aint Valid, username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    End If


    If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 8. Is Valid, Username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    Else
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 9. Aint Valid, username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    End If


    If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 10. Is Valid, Username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    Else
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 11. Aint Valid, username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    End If


    If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 12. Is Valid, Username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    Else
        log.Debug("Loginerror: 13. Aint Valid, username: " & Login1.UserName.Trim)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the exact same issue all of a sudden, and would be interesed to hear what you found.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I was never able to resolve this issue and never got around to finalizy my thread.

So I had to do a work around to get my Website working again.
When the Login failes, I check if the User is existing in the database. If this is the case I then Authorize the user and set the Login Cookies.

```
          If e.Authenticated = False Then
            'Init Base User, check if System works
            Try
                user1 = New BenutzerVerwaltung.clsUser()
            Catch ex As Exception
                showMessage("Loginfehler: Basis Benutzer")
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            'Check if User exists
            Try
                user1.loadUser(Login1.UserName.Trim)
            Catch ex As Exception
                showMessage("LoginFehler: Benutzer Ini")
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            Try
                'Manually Validate user and set Authentication Cookies.
                If (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName.Trim, Login1.Password)) Then
                    e.Authenticated = True
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, True)
                Else
                    e.Authenticated = False
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                showMessage("LoginFehler: MB-Framework")
                Exit Sub
            End Try

          End If
```